# ¿Cómo crear marcas dentro de un mapa?

Tags: html5, web, geolocalización

Quizás es una consulta básica, pero no puedo hacerlo, ¿Cómo puedo crear marcas dentro de un mapa que me muestren, por ejemplo, un local? Este es mi mapa, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```js
function success(position) {
  var status = document.querySelector('#status');
  status.innerHTML = "¡Le encontramos!";
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';   
  mapcanvas.style.width = '560px';
  document.querySelector('#map').appendChild(mapcanvas);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,  
    navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    position: latlng,
  map: map,
  title:"Usted está aqui."
});}
function error(msg)
{
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML= "Error [" + error.code + "]: " + error.message;
} 
if (navigator.geolocation) 
{ 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error,{maximumAge:60000, timeout: 4000}); 
} else {
  error('Su navegador no tiene soporte para su geolocalización');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset=ISO-8859-1 />
    <title>Geolocalización con HTML5</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <h1>Geolocalización con HTML5</h1>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <p id="status">Buscando su localización...</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con "No puedo hacerlo" ? No aparece la marca en tu mapa? No es el tipo de marca que quieres mostrar? Aparece la marca pero no la burbuja de información?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple vista veo varios fallos de javascript, pero el principal es que necesitas un APIKEY para acceder a los mapas. Si le echas un vistazo a la documentación de Google Maps vas a encontrar muchos ejemplos de como hacer lo que pides.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo sencillo para pintar un mapa: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=es-419

Y aquí tienes uno de como pintar un marcador:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es-419

Cuando hagas programación web tambien te aconsejo que tengas la consola de desarrollo de tu navegador abierta. Te va a hacer mucha falta, sobre todo cuando empiezas :D

Comment: gracias, ahora con el segundo link que pusiste pude hacerlo, no se porque aparece con error aqui ,revisare  la apikey,